# Thread not updating but blocking on recv()

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, tcp, recv

I am making a multi-threaded TCP server, when I use recv() in the threads, they do not update/execute/run infinitely (looping), unless recv() actually receives some data.

Here is a code snippet from inside the loop.

```
if( seconds < 15 ){
    printf("%f seconds passed: \r", seconds);

    if ( (read_size = recv(sock , client_message , 512 , 0)) > 0 )
    {
      //Send the message back to client
      reply_message = client_message;
      (void)write(sock, reply_message, strlen(reply_message));
    }

}else{
    // ... blah blah blah
}
```

If I comment out the internal IF statement, the thread runs & outputs printf() as fast as it can. When the IF statement is included, the thread waits on recv() and will not update ( printf() isn't printed ) until recv() has received data :/

Any ideas?

Comment: Well that's what it's supposed to do. What were you expecting it to do?

Comment: It should continuously print out seconds passed up to 15 seconds while also receiving data. However, when recv() is used it doesn't and other conditional statements based of the seconds variable aren't executing because of recv() halting the thread.

Comment: You want to combine `select` with a 1-second timeout with `recv`. Also you want to set the socket to non-blocking. Also you need to handle short reads...

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2295737/694576

Comment: '`recv()` halting [you mean 'blocking'] the thread' is what's supposed to happen. Your question remains unclear.

Answer (score 1):

From recv(2) - Linux man page (see [here](http://linux.die.net/man/2/recv)):

> If no messages are available at the socket, the receive calls wait for
>   a message to arrive, unless the socket is nonblocking (see fcntl(2)),
>   in which case the value -1 is returned and the external variable errno
>   is set to EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK. The receive calls normally return any
>   data available, up to the requested amount, rather than waiting for
>   receipt of the full amount requested.

So it's the way how `recv` works. If you want it to return immediately you should use non-blocking mode (see [`fcntl`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fcntl) and [`select`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) desriptions).

```
// sock is the socket you want to make non-blocking
int status = fcntl(sock, F_SETFL, fcntl(sock, F_GETFL, 0) | O_NONBLOCK);

// handle the error
if(status == -1) {
    ...
}
```

If you want to check if there anything to read in socket

```
int count = 0;
ioctl(sock, FIONREAD, &count);
```

`count` is the number of bytes available in the socket